# Fedora Linux VM guest: How to change screen resolution

Tags: virtualbox, fedora, resolution

I'm running Fedora Linux 16 as guest system, inside a Windows/VirtualBox host. After install the provided add-ons, only 1024x768 screen resolution displays properly; when I try to increase it, I cannot see my Gnome bottom bar... how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [SOLVED] I solve this problem following this tutorial: http://bit.ly/8LPveA